# Apple sign-in invalid_client

Tags: ios, applescript

Im developing a web application with apple sign-in and Im getting invalid_client error.
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1ZxE.jpg)

my apple js button

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appleid.cdn-apple.com/appleauth/static/jsapi/appleid/1/en_US/appleid.auth.js"></script>
    <div id="appleid-signin" data-color="black" data-border="true" data-type="sign in"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        AppleID.auth.init({
            clientId : 'NVNY9NG38Y',
            scope : 'scope=email',
            redirectURI : 'https://www.annastudio.beauty/appoint',
            state : 'Initial user authentication request',
            usePopup : true
        });
    </script>
```

i really dont know what to do since they dont explain what gone wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To start, check without any unnecessary parameters and ensure that the required parameters clientId and redirectURI are correct. Verify that the clientId is in the correct format, I think it should be smth like `com.<app-name>.<>`. Also, verify that the redirectURI used in the code matches the exact URL specified in the Apple Developer Console for your app.